# Detect if WCF service is throttling

Tags: wcf, throttling

Is there any way to detect on server-side if my maxConcurrentSessions or maxConcurrentCalls have been exhausted, i.e. calls to my service have been queued? I'd like log this if I can. Alternatively, does IIS offer any help?

Answer (score 0):

To detect the current concurrent Sessions you could try to add a static int field to your ServiceClass:

```
public class MyService : IMyService, IDisposable
{
    // Service Instance Count
    private static int _NumberOfInstances;

    public MyService () 
    {
        MyService._NumberOfInstances++;
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyService._NumberOfInstances--;
    }
}
```

By definition: 
ConcurrentInstances is the number of service instances that are allocated at a given time. When it’s PerCall services, this value matches the number of concurrent calls. For PerSession services, this value equals the number of active session instances.

So you would be able the check if you are going to exceed your max-values.

Answer (score 0):

[WCF performance counters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/29/less-tweaking-of-your-wcf-4-0-apps-for-high-throughput-workloads.aspx) were available when you asked your question.